# UMS threads deadlocked with no error code

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, deadlock, scheduling

I'm trying to implement a simple UMS sample program, but it always deadlocks for no obvious reason.

Microsoft gives no sample code to start from, so this is mostly written from scratch.

The only info they give on UMS is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/user-mode-scheduling

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    PUMS_COMPLETION_LIST completionList;

    CreateUmsCompletionList(&completionList);

    SIZE_T attrsize = 0ULL;

    InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(nullptr, 1, 0, &attrsize);

    LPPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST attributes = reinterpret_cast<LPPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST>(malloc(attrsize));

    memset(attributes, 0, attrsize);

    InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(attributes, 1, 0, &attrsize);

    PUMS_CONTEXT   umsContext;

    CreateUmsThreadContext(&umsContext);
    
    UMS_CREATE_THREAD_ATTRIBUTES umsattribs =
    {
        .UmsVersion = UMS_VERSION,
        .UmsContext = umsContext,
        .UmsCompletionList = completionList
    };

    UpdateProcThreadAttribute(attributes, 0, PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_UMS_THREAD, &umsattribs, sizeof(umsattribs), nullptr, nullptr);

    CloseHandle(CreateRemoteThreadEx(GetCurrentProcess(), nullptr, 0,
        [](LPVOID lpThreadParameter)->DWORD
        {
            std::cout << "task started!\n";

            UmsThreadYield(0);

            std::cout << "task executed\n";

            return 0;
        },
        0, 0, attributes, nullptr));

    DeleteProcThreadAttributeList(attributes);
    free(attributes);


    UMS_SCHEDULER_STARTUP_INFO umsinfo =
    {
        .UmsVersion = UMS_VERSION,
        .CompletionList = completionList,
        .SchedulerProc = [](UMS_SCHEDULER_REASON Reason, ULONG_PTR ActivationPayload, PVOID SchedulerParam)
        {
            PUMS_COMPLETION_LIST completionList = reinterpret_cast<PUMS_COMPLETION_LIST>(SchedulerParam);
            PUMS_CONTEXT UmsThreadList = nullptr;
            do {
                if (Reason == UmsSchedulerThreadYield)
                {
                    std::cout << "yielded\n";
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    switch (Reason)
                    {
                    case UmsSchedulerStartup:
                        std::cout << "startup\n";
                        break;


                    case UmsSchedulerThreadBlocked:
                        std::cout << "blocked\n";
                        break;
                    }
                }
                for (;;)
                {

                    if (DequeueUmsCompletionListItems(completionList, INFINITE, &UmsThreadList) && UmsThreadList)
                    {

                        GetNextUmsListItem(UmsThreadList);

                        BOOLEAN flag;

                        QueryUmsThreadInformation(completionList, UmsThreadIsTerminated, &flag, sizeof(flag), nullptr);
                        if (flag) {
                            std::cout << "terminated\n";
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } while (false);
            do
            {
                ExecuteUmsThread(UmsThreadList);
                if(GetLastError() != ERROR_RETRY)throw 1;
            } while (GetLastError() == ERROR_RETRY);
            return;
        },
        .SchedulerParam = completionList
    };

    EnterUmsSchedulingMode(&umsinfo);

    DeleteUmsThreadContext(umsContext);

    std::cout << "program Terminated!\n";
}
```

Comment: UMS was deprecated since Windows 8, and in Windows 11 it is gone entirely. The documentation needs to be updated. I'll submit a documentation change request.

Comment: @RaymondChen if it's gonna be removed will cooperative scheduling no longer be possible?

Comment: This API is no longer functional today. Your follow-up question is about the future. Making predictions is hard, especially about the future.

Comment: [Fibers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/fibers) still work, so coöperative scheduling is still possible. Fibers just [aren't very useful](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20191011-00/?p=102989), so presumably the question should read: *"Will **useful** coöperative scheduling no longer be possible?"*

Comment: @IInspectable that was implied

Comment: @RaymondChen Why do you believe it is obsolete? Do you have any evidence of this?

Comment: @Badasahog Try to use it on Windows 11. All calls return `ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED`. That's pretty strong evidence if you ask me.

Comment: @RaymondChen I see. Do you know why this change is being made? Also, isn't this a pretty significant breaking change?

Comment: @Badasahog It turns out that the change has zero practical impact because there are no apps that use the UMS APIs.

Comment: Then why was it removed? security?

Comment: @Badasahog There's no point spending engineering resources maintaining a feature that nobody is using.